# Cancelling an InnoSetup installer

Tags: inno-setup, pascal

**Situation**

During the installation of our product I detect if our programs are still running (from a previous installation) by using CheckForMutexes. If our programs are still running I pop up a message box (by using MsgBox) that tells the user to close the programs. If the user clicks the ok and they haven't closed our programs, the same message box is displayed. I'd like to display a cancel button in the MsgBox that aborts the installation, which would be desired in the case the user doesn't want to close the running programs.

**Question**

How can I abort an InnoSetup install programmatically?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`InitializeSetup`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents) and [`Abort`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_abort) in the Inno Setup help.  The `Abort` function will allow the setup to exit.

Comment: This will not exit the setup unless it is called from inside a specific event functions, like InitializeSetup, InitializeWizard or CurStepChanged, which is not the case.

Answer (score -1):

Call the WizardForm.Close() method.

It will prompt the user if she really wants to cancel the installation.

```
procedure ExitSetup;
begin
  WizardForm.Close;
end;
```

Comment: @Tamir, please read the question, OP states they check for programs running, and there's no way to check that before the wizard starts, if I'm right.